# How to create Custom Heading Styles for multiple Table of Contents in Microsoft Word by using vb.net code?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm currently working as an intern at the National Institute of Aviation Research(NIAR) and have been tasked with creating a report generator. The report generator will fetch all data graphs, pictures, documents, etc. within the network drive and merge them into one main report document. The problem I am facing is how do I manage 4 different table of contents? I know I can just make custom heading styles in Microsoft Word itself, however, everyone using the software will not have those custom heading styles available unless they create them. Is there a way to dynamically create heading styles using vb.net?

For example, I want to create custom heading style "CustomHeader"

then I want to use the vb.net command below:
document.paragraphs(document.paragraphs.count).Range.Style = "CustomHeader"

Thank you in advance,

-Rueben Ramirez

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share what you've tried and where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: You can try something like this: https://janewdaisy.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/how-to-manage-headings-in-word-document-with-cvb-net/

Comment: Sure you can create styles using VB.NET. Best way to get started is to record a macro creating the style in the Word application then look at the VBA code it generates. That will give you the necessary objects/properties/methods. You should also consider providing the users with TEMPLATES to use when creating a certain type of document. These can be customized to make it easy for the users to apply the "preferred" formatting (styles)...

Comment: Temporary fix that I've tried was separating each table of contents into their own document and updating the fields there with the default header styles. After that I would merge the four documents together without updating fields so contents of one TOC wouldnt show up in another. That is assuming no changes will be made to the report after.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!

Comment: I ended up finding the library within vb.net to simply create a style. Create a word document and then reference the "Styles" library.

Comment: Dim document As word.document - document.Styles.Add("CustomHeader")